# Cannot turn script back on

Tags: unity, c#

I've got an issue. When `(Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)`, `Speedy` script is disabled, thus we cannot enable it again from inside the script like shown below. How can we go around this?

```
public class  Speedy : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject car;

 if (speed == good)
    {
        GameObject car = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Car");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) 
        {
            car.GetComponent<Speedy>().enabled = false;
        }

        else car.GetComponent<Speedy>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more an architecture issue than a problem with an `if` statement. Check for your mouse click outside Speedy, and activate or deactivate it from there.

Comment: @Almo Title edited.

Comment: once you disabled script so how do you expect to run same script to enable it? which is now disable?

Comment: @HamzaHasan That's my question. Is there another way?

Comment: Control all of these operations from another class.

Comment: Ok, let me write a short answer for you

Comment: First clear me first that do you want to enable/disable only script or gameObject on which this script is attached?

Comment: @HamzaHasan I want to disable the script.

Comment: If a script disables itself (or in any way becomes disabled) it *cannot reenable itself* ***because it cannot run!***  It is disabled!

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use `FindObjectOfType` either.

`FindObjectOfType` gives you reference on relevant script once then you can play with it.

If I edit your code, then it should be something like this

```
public class  Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    Speedy car;

    Start()
    {
        car = FindObjectOfType<Speedy>();
    }

     if (speed == good)
        {

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) 
            {
                car.enabled = false;
            }

            else car.enabled = true;
        }

}
```

Drop this script to another `GameObject` in hierarchy.

**NOTE:** In your question you are disabling script from `car` but enabling if from `cube`. I don't know that you did it intentionally.